# Automatically set security attributes when moving files with Win32 API ? (C#)

Tags: c#, file, uwp

I'm currently developing an app that have to move a file to another application folder. But the other application must have a specific permissions on files that are copied.
When I use the Win32 API to MoveFileFromApp (it's uwp app), it doesn't update the security attributes to inherit the folder.
here is the code of MoveFile (C#)

```cs
[DllImport("api-ms-win-core-file-fromapp-l1-1-0.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, 
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveFileFromApp(
string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName);
```

Does anyone know how to set these security permissions for the folder automatically during the moving process ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Could you please tell me what `the other application must have a specific permissions on files that are copied` means? Is the “specific permissions on files” the permissions mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)?

Comment: Hello, sorry for my bad precision about that. It means that the other application load the file, and it must have a sort of "read access", it's a "Unknow User" SID that must be on the file for the app to read it

Comment: Could you please tell whether you move a file from one disk to another disk(such as form C disk to D disk)? In UWP, there is no such API could set the read/write permission.

Comment: Hello, I move the disk only from destination to another in the same disk. I was wondering if there is a way with System.IO, or even Win32 API

Comment: You could try to use a Win32 API [SetFileSecurityA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setfilesecuritya) which sets the security of a file or directory object.

Comment: Hello, I'm very interested by that. I've tried using SetNamedFileSecurity but I can't find what to put in parameters :(

Comment: My real question with that SetNamedSecurity is, how to inherit automatically ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use `SetNamedSecurityInfo` method by **P/Invoke** in UWP app with the following code. The error [ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)(error code is 5) always exists in UWP app. But in Win32, the usage of `SetNamedSecurityInfo` method with the value `UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` to inherit the security attributes  is successful.

In UWP, there are some limitations on file system access permission. Though the `SetNamedSecurityInfo` method can be called successfully, it does not work as expected.

The code to use SetNamedSecurityInfo method in UWP:

```
public uint DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000004;
public uint UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x20000000;
public uint ACL_REVISION = 0x2;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ACL
{
    public byte AclRevision;
    public byte Sbz1;
    public ushort AclSize;
    public ushort AceCount;
    public ushort Sbz2;
}
public enum SE_OBJECT_TYPE
{
    SE_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_TYPE = 0,
    SE_FILE_OBJECT,
    SE_SERVICE,
    SE_PRINTER,
    SE_REGISTRY_KEY,
    SE_LMSHARE,
    SE_KERNEL_OBJECT,
    SE_WINDOW_OBJECT,
    SE_DS_OBJECT,
    SE_DS_OBJECT_ALL,
    SE_PROVIDER_DEFINED_OBJECT,
    SE_WMIGUID_OBJECT,
    SE_REGISTRY_WOW64_32KEY,
    SE_REGISTRY_WOW64_64KEY,
}

[DllImport("api-ms-win-core-file-fromapp-l1-1-0.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveFileFromAppW(
    string lpExistingFileName,
    string lpNewFileName);

[DllImport("advapi32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern uint SetNamedSecurityInfo(
    string lpFileName,
    SE_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType,
    uint SecurityInfo,
    IntPtr psidOwner,
    IntPtr psidGroup,
    ref ACL pDacl,
    IntPtr pSacl);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool InitializeAcl(ref ACL pAcl, int nAclLength, uint dwAclRevision);

[DllImport("api-ms-win-core-file-fromapp-l1-1-0.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveFileFromApp(
string lpExistingFileName,
string lpNewFileName
);

public void SetFilePermission(string FileName)
{//Use the method to let the file inherit the security attributes from parent object
    bool ret = false;
    ACL pDacl = new ACL();
    ret = InitializeAcl(ref pDacl, Marshal.SizeOf<ACL>(), ACL_REVISION);
    uint SecurityInfo = DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION;
    uint err = SetNamedSecurityInfo(FileName, SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_FILE_OBJECT, SecurityInfo, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, ref pDacl, IntPtr.Zero);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'm seeing this right now ! My app has RunFullTrust and broadFileSystemAccess so maybe it will not have errors
EDIT: I've seen why you have access denied :) It's because you are using advapi32.dll, there is another Dll for UWP (api-ms-win-security-provider-l1-1-0.dll)
EDIT2 : Here is the page for Win32 API UWP : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis

Comment: I have just a last question : Why does this remove all DACL/SACL ? Because I need then to click on the file and give admin to re set dacl and sacl

Comment: The reason why removing all DACL is to let the file inherit its parent folder’s security. You could choose not remove them.

Comment: If I remove them, will the file Inherit from parent folder (SID of the account that own the parent folder) ?

Comment: [UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-information): The DACL inherits ACEs from the parent object. And, UNPROTECTED_SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION: The SACL inherits ACEs from the parent object.

Comment: I tried that but it keep the permission that MoveFile gave :(